# Can D-Wave presently solve real-world problems that conventional computers cannot solve?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, d-wave, annealing

There are number of threads on this site about the ability of QCs solving real-world problems (see for example [What are the practical applications of quantum computing in engineering by the year 2030?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/what-are-the-practical-applications-of-quantum-computing-in-engineering-by-the-y), [Is quantum computing just pie in the sky?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/is-quantum-computing-just-pie-in-the-sky) and [What kind of real-world problems (excluding cryptography) can be solved efficiently by a quantum algorithm?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/what-kind-of-real-world-problems-excluding-cryptography-can-be-solved-efficien?noredirect=1&lq=1).   Reading through the answers and comments I note that QCs are not quite there yet and it will take one or two more decades to get there.  Also, with specific reference to D-wave’s quantum annealing technology, there is a very good recent thread: [Did D-Wave show quantum advantage in 2023?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34011/did-d-wave-show-quantum-advantage-in-2023). A thorough and leading answer argues that even computers based on quantum annealing cannot presently solve real-world problems and it concludes verbatim “…so quantum annealers remain as a specialized resource in a very small number of HPC centers, where they can be used by academics to play.”

Looking at D-wave website, on the other hand, one immediately realizes that they are a very “business-centric” company, with customers in logistics, portfolio optimization, drug discovery, materials sciences, scheduling, fault detection, traffic congestion, etc.  Since D-Wave is a publically traded company, it is natural to assume that the stakeholders put a strong revenue stream and profitability ahead of pure academic play. Their customers include reputable companies and they outline a number of business success stories on their site.  In fact, last night their CEO Alan Baratz was on Bloomberg Technology (see 24:27 minutes into the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZSL8lnTkrs)) , promoting D-wave’s capabilities for real-world business.

So the question on my mind: Is D-Wave presently really solving problems for customers that they (the customers) themselves could otherwise not solve with conventional computers?

Comment: also related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27294/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11796/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/171/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1366/55

Comment: The article published by Michael Brooks in Nature in May 2023 “Quantum computers: what are they good for?” gives a broad overview of where things stand at the moment and where we need to go so QCs can actually do something useful:     https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01692-9#ref-CR2. I found all references there also very useful.